# Expected Value and Variance of Linear and Nonlinear discrete-time Models with additive noise

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Suppose we have

1) a stochastic Linear discrete-time Model given by:
${x_k} = A_{k-1}{x_{k - 1}} + {v_{k - 1}}$
, where ${v_{k - 1}} \sim N(0,\sigma _v^2)$ and $A$ is generally a known matrix.

and 2) a stochastic nonlinear discrete-time Model given by:
${x_k} = f_{k-1}({x_{k - 1}}) + {v_{k - 1}}$
, where $f$ is a some known function.

Find the following statistics for these models:

a1) $E[X_{k}|X_{k-1}]$ = ?

b1) $E[X_{k}]$ = ?

c1) Var: $E[(X_{k} - E[X_{k}])^2]$ = ?

d1) COVar:$E[(X_{k} - E[X_{k}])(X_{k-1} - E[X_{k-1}])] $= ?

---

a2) $E[X_{k}|X_{k-1}]$ = ?

b2) $E[X_{k}]$ = ?

c2) Var: $E[(X_{k} - E[X_{k}])^2] $= ?

d2) COVar: $E[(X_{k} - E[X_{k}])(X_{k-1} - E[X_{k-1}])] $= ?

Comment: do you mean the unconditional variance or a conditional variance? $E[(X_{k} - E[X_{k}])^2]$ or $E[(X_{k} - E[X_{k}])^2|X_{k-1}]$ or $E[(X_{k} - E[X_{k}])^2|Y_{1:k}]$ or $E[(X_{k} - E[X_{k}])^2|Y_{1:k-1}]$

Comment: @Taylor the unconditional variance.

Comment: It would be also most helpful if you can provide an answer for those conditional variances above. Thank you for your time and consideration in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.
Assuming $k=1,2,\ldots$ and $X_1 \sim \text{Normal}(0, \sigma^2/(1-A^2))$, and $A$ is constant for all time points (a homogeneous Markov chain):

For the non-conditional expectations and variances you want to use the law of total expectation and the law of total variance.

a) $E[X_{k}|X_{k-1}] = E[A X_{k-1} + v_{k-1}|X_{k-1}] = AX_{k-1} + 0$ (linearity of expectations)

b) $E[X_k] = E[E[X_k|X_{k-1}]]= 0$ (since we're starting in the stationary distribution). Try this for $k=2$, then proceed inductively.

c) \begin{align*}
\text{Var}[X_k] &= \text{Var}[E(X_k|X_{k-1})] + E[\text{Var}(X_k|X_{k-1})] \\
&= \text{Var}[AX_{k-1}] + E[\sigma^2_v] \\
&= \text{Var}[AX_{k-1}] + \sigma^2_v \\
&= A^2 \frac{\sigma_V^2}{1-A^2} + \sigma^2_v \\
&= \sigma^2
\end{align*}

The whole key is assuming that the first state is in the stationary distribution. Then, because the Markov Chain is stationary, it stays in that stationary distribution. b) shows the unconditional mean is constant at $0$, and $c$ shows that unconditional variance stays at $\sigma^2_v$. Then, by properties of normality, the marginal distributions are normal.

If you do not start off in the stationary distribution, you'll still get closer to it after every time point, assuming $-1 < A < 1$. You can use the same math above to show this.

d) For the covariance you want to use bilinearity. 
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(X_k,X_{k-1}) &= \text{Cov}(AX_{k-1}+v_{k-1},X_{k-1}) \\
&= A\text{Cov}(X_{k-1},X_{k-1}) + 0 \\
&= A \text{Var}(X_{k-1}) \\
&= A \sigma^2_v.
\end{align*}

For the non-linear one, it's still the same math again. Just replace $Ax_{k-1}$ with $f(x_{k-1})$ everywhere. The answer will depend on whether or not you assume you start off in some stationary distribution, which depends on your specific $f$. I leave it to you to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you very much. My question now is why you consider that $X_1$ has the stationary distribution of a Markov chain? In fact, I would question whether this assumption always holds?

Comment: And my second question is, if we can take for example $f = x_{k-1}^2$ , now what is the distribution of $X_k$?

Comment: @sci9 see edits. Also, I changed the tag to be Markov-CHAIN because "process" usually refers to continuous time stuff, which this is not

Comment: Merci beaucoup. ;-)