# Likelihood of a state space model with multiplicative noise $p(y_k|x_k) = ? $

Tags: conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, state-space-models

Consider the following state space model: the transition distribution of the latent variable $x_k$ along with the observational density is given below. Assume that both sequences of the noise terms, $\{{v_k}\}$ and $\{{w_k}\}$, are iid Gaussian. What is the probabilistic model of the observation equation $p(y_k|x_k)$?

$$\begin{array}{l}
{x_k} = {x_{k - 1}} + {w_k}\\
{y_k} = {x_k} \times {v_k}
\end{array}$$

---

Note: in the case of an additive noise we have 
$$ p({y_k}|{x_k}) = {p_v}({v_k} = {y_k} - {x_k}) =  \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } \sigma }}\exp \{ \frac{{ - .5{{({y_k} - {x_k})}^2}}}{{{\sigma ^2}}}\} $$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still Gaussian, but the state is affecting the scale, not the location of the observaions. Here $x_k$ represents the standard deviation of $y_k$. So

$$
y_k|x_k \sim \text{Gaussian}(y_k;0, x_k^2).
$$

But beware, sometimes you'll have a negative standard deviation. You probably don't want that. If you're trying to do a stochastic volatility model, they are typically done with the following observational density (assuming we keep your state transition dynamics):

$$
y_k = \beta e^{x_k/2}z_k
$$
where $\beta >0$ is some constant representing "modal volatility", and $x_k$ now represents the log-variance. Also, $\{z_k\}$ are just iid standard (mean zero, variance 1) normal rvs. Exponentiating it keeps it positive.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So is it correct to say that the probabilistic model for the observation equation ${y_k} = \beta {e^{{x_k}/2}}{z_k}$, is  ${y_k}|{x_k}\sim{\rm{Gaussian}}({y_k};0,\beta {e^{{x_k}/2}})$?

Comment: Could you please answer my question in the link below? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252324

Comment: @sci9 regarding your first question it would be ${y_k}|{x_k}\sim{\rm{Gaussian}}({y_k};0,\beta^2 {e^{{x_k}}})$. It's analagous to saying something like if $Z \sim \rm{Gaussian}(0,1)$ then $\mu  + \sigma Z \sim \rm{Gaussian}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. when you take the variance of something the scale gets squared

Comment: @sci9 sure I'll take a look

Comment: Merci beaucoup.